# Origin corner of a VRT file

Tags: gdal, vrt

I'm writting a pure Python lib to read VRT files and I'm struggling to understand a spec of the VRT format: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html.

When a source is added in a `SimpleSource` tag, on should add the positioning of the source with respect to the global VRT:

```xml
<SimpleSource>
  <SourceFilename relativeToVRT="1">utm.tif</SourceFilename>
  <OpenOptions>
      <OOI key="OVERVIEW_LEVEL">0</OOI>
  </OpenOptions>
  <SourceBand>1</SourceBand>
  <SourceProperties RasterXSize="256" RasterYSize="256" DataType="Byte" BlockXSize="128" BlockYSize="128"/>
  <SrcRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="256" ySize="256"/>
  <DstRect xOff="0" yOff="0" xSize="256" ySize="256"/>
</SimpleSource>
```

but what is the source corner of the .vrt format ?

I tried bottom-left but it's not. I'm going to try the four others afterward but can anyone reference documentation where this is specified?

Comment: It seems to be top left from some experiments, but I can't find a reference in the docs: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html

Comment: after some testing I can confirm it's top-left. documentation seems to be missing though

Comment: Image pixels always start at top left, it's not just a GDAL convention. This is why the Y size in a geotransform (and world file) is a negative value (as pixel Y index increases, map Y coordinate decreases).

Comment: You can update the docs

Comment: they beat me to it: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/pull/7577, I'll wait for a merge and publish it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation have been updated: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html#vrtdataset

> **GeoTransform**: This element contains a six value affine geotransformation for the dataset, mapping between pixel/line coordinates and georeferenced coordinates. Typically (geotransform[0], geotransform[3]) will be the (easting, northing) of the upper-left corner of the raster, geotransform[1] the horizontal resolution in geospatial coordinates/pixel, and geotransform[5] the vertical resolution in geospatial coordinates/pixel, as a negative value if the image is north-up oriented. See Affine GeoTransform for more details about that mapping.

so the origin will depend from your transform, in a typical image, x > 0, y < 0 means that origin is top-left.